# how to read offset in the middle of an InputStream?

Tags: java, byte, inputstream, fileinputstream

here's my file C://test.txt compose of 
ACBDE
FGHIJ

i wanted to read it start from F all the way to J.
so the output is FGHIJ. how will i do that in InputStream read using offset.
here's my partial implementaion.

```
InputStream is = null;
byte[] buffer = null;
char c;

try {
    is = new FileInputStream("D://test.txt");
    buffer = new byte[is.available()];
    System.out.println("Characters printed:");
    is.read(buffer, 5, 5);
    for (byte b : buffer) {

        if (b == 0)
            // if b is empty
            c = '-';
        else
            c = (char) b;

        System.out.print(c);
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (is != null)
        is.close();
}
```

please help me with my probelm :D

Answer (score 2):

The `offset` parameter of `read()` is the offset into the buffer, not the file. What you are looking for is the `seek()` method, followed by a `read()` with an offset of zero.

NB This is a classic misuse of `available()`. See the Javadoc. There is a specific warning against using it as the length of the input stream.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to to start by the nth character you could do this:

```
 public static void file_foreach_offset( String file, int offset, IntConsumer c) throws IOException {

        try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))) {
            stream.flatMapToInt(String::chars)
                  .skip(offset)
                  .forEach(c);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)),the second parameter is **"the start offset in the destination array"** not file offset ,I think you mistaken this,so you can try read all of this then find first space char then start printing,like this:

```
InputStream is = null;
    byte[] buffer = null;
    char c;
    boolean canPrint = false;

    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("/Users/smy/test.txt");
        buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        System.out.println("Characters printed:"+is.available());
        is.read(buffer, 0, is.available());
        for (byte b : buffer) {

            if ((char)b == ' ')
                // if b is empty
                canPrint = true;
            else{
                c = (char) b;

                if (canPrint){
                    System.out.print(c);
                }}
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null)
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Or you can use [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to set offset for the file then start reading.

Comment: actually, the requirements is to use a source which is inputstream. then traverse it or read it somewhere in the middle of the bytes..

Comment: If you can't access the stream with offset,you can read it one by one like my codes show.